# Passing PIPE handle to the child process

Tags: debugging, winapi, createprocess

I'm creating a child process using `CreateProcess`. I've created a *pipe* in the main application and I want it to be used by the child process which is *not* a console application.

Is there any way to do this? I can pass it using command line but this might really be a bad solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use named pipes as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and pass the pipe name in the lpCcommandLine parameter of `CreateProcess`.

Or (not sure if this works, I never tried) set the bInheritHandles parameter of `CreateProcess` to TRUE and pass the handle as a hexadecimal value in the lpCcommandLine parameter.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not allowed to use commandline for this purpose.

Comment: What's wrong with passing information on the command line ? However if you cannot do this you can provide some unique name such as "\\\\.\\pipe\\myuniquespecialpipename" and use this name in  the main application and in the child process.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need special tricks.
Tested: When you start a GUI application with standard io redirected to pipes, they work just like in console application:

test.bat

```
@echo off
gui.exe | find /v "__nonexist__"
pause
```

output:

```
WriteFile
puts
```

child.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE h;
    TCHAR tstr[100];
    DWORD nb;
    h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    _stprintf(tstr, _T("0x%08x"), h);
    MessageBox(NULL, tstr, _T("x"), MB_OK);
#define sWriteFile "WriteFile\n"
#define sPuts "puts\n"
    if (h) {
        WriteFile(h, sWriteFile, sizeof(sWriteFile)-1, &nb, NULL);
        fputs(sPuts, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    return _tmain(0, NULL);
}
```

When you start a GUI program from console, standard handles are closed, but there's a way to reopen them. This trick is used in netbeans.exe